# como sustituir una llamada ajax por otra

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo uan ligera duda sobre como sustituir un elemento por otro dentro de un `for`, en este caso hago una llada a un ´$.post´ que recoge un json y lo muetra en uan especie de carta por decirlo de alguna manera, la información la recoge bien, y los datos los muestra como deberia, el problema es que cuando previamente ya he hecho una llamda y hago otra disdinta con otra información, en lugar de sustituir se añade y pues... en este caso no queda bien, bueno ya despues de esta medio introducción procedo a mostrarles el codigo que tengo y la captura de la misma ya pido disculpas de antmano si no me entienden. El codigo jquery es el siguiente

```
$.post('.show_bookmarks.php',{id_sub_categoria:id_sub_categoria},
    function(response){
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(response);
        for(var i in response){
            // console.log(response[i]);
            $('#add').prepend(

                $('<a/>',{'href':response[i].url}).append(
                    $('<div/>',{'id':'my_card','class':'col s12 m3'}).append(
                        $('<div/>',{'class':'card'}).append(
                            $('<div/>',{'class':'mi-card-image card-image'}).append(
                                $('<img/>',{'src':'ficheros/bookmark/'+response[i].fichero}),
                                $('<a/>',{'class':'btn-floating fav-edit-del waves-effect waves-light yellow darken-2','onclick':'add_favoritos('+response[i].id+')'}).append(
                                    $('<i/>',{'class':'material-icons','html': 'star_border'})
                                ),
                                $('<a/>',{'class':'btn-floating fav-edit-del waves-effect waves-light blue','onclick':'add_favoritos('+response[i].id+')'}).append(
                                    $('<i/>',{'class':'material-icons','html': 'edit'})
                                ),
                                 $('<a/>',{'class':'btn-floating fav-edit-del waves-effect waves-light red','onclick':'add_favoritos('+response[i].id+')'}).append(
                                    $('<i/>',{'class':'material-icons','html': 'clear'})
                                )
                            ),
                            $('<div/>',{'class':'card-content'}).append($('<span/>',{'class':'card-title ','html':response[i].titulo}),$('<p/>').html(
                                response[i].notas+'<br>'+
                                'usuario: '+response[i].usuario+'<br/>'+
                                'password: '+response[i].password
                                )),


                        )
                    )
                )


            );
        }

    });
```

las capturas son las siguientes:
lo que está señalado en rojo donde hago clic y mustra la información
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego hago la llamada a Age of empires (son ejemplos) y se añade a la linea
y pues muestra algo muy similar (como debe ser) pero deberian desaparecer las dos anteriores y mostrar la que he clicado, no sé si me explico muy bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

un saludo a todos y espero que me puedan ayudar
Gracias.

Comment: Ya probaste a limpiar tu caja antes de cada ciclo

$('#add').html("");

O a ocultarlas

$('#add a').hide();

$('#add a').hide(); //Para mostrar de nuevo :)

Saludos :)

Comment: quieres decir, arriba del `for` hacer con `.html("")`, me lo puedes mostrar un ejemplo por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer un vaciado de las cajas antes de volver a llenarlas:

```
$('#add').empty();
$('#add').prepend(...)
```

Comment: me ha funcionado muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Algo asi mira

```
    $.post('.show_bookmarks.php',{id_sub_categoria:id_sub_categoria},
        function(response){

$('#add').html("");

            response = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);
            for(var i in response){
                // console.log(response[i]);
                $('#add').prepend(

                    $('<a/>',{'href':response[i].url}).append(
                        $('<div/>',{'id':'my_card','class':'col s12 m3'}).append(
                            $('<div/>',{'class':'card'}).append(
                                $('<div/>',{'class':'mi-card-image card-image'}).append(
                                    $('<img/>',{'src':'ficheros/bookmark/'+response[i].fichero}),
                                    $('<a/>',{'class':'btn-floating fav-edit-del waves-effect waves-light yellow darken-2','onclick':'add_favoritos('+response[i].id+')'}).append(
                                        $('<i/>',{'class':'material-icons','html': 'star_border'})
                                    ),
                                    $('<a/>',{'class':'btn-floating fav-edit-del waves-effect waves-light blue','onclick':'add_favoritos('+response[i].id+')'}).append(
                                        $('<i/>',{'class':'material-icons','html': 'edit'})
                                    ),
                                     $('<a/>',{'class':'btn-floating fav-edit-del waves-effect waves-light red','onclick':'add_favoritos('+response[i].id+')'}).append(
                                        $('<i/>',{'class':'material-icons','html': 'clear'})
                                    )
                                ),
                                $('<div/>',{'class':'card-content'}).append($('<span/>',{'class':'card-title ','html':response[i].titulo}),$('<p/>').html(
                                    response[i].notas+'<br>'+
                                    'usuario: '+response[i].usuario+'<br/>'+
                                    'password: '+response[i].password
                                    )),


                            )
                        )
                    )


                );
            }

        });
```

Comment: O usar la función que nos recomienda Javier Molla $('#add').empty();

Comment: WOO me funciona muchas gracias por la colaboracion!!! yo estaba pensado en una fucioon que ocultase las cosas jajaja un saludo y gracias!